# Chrome Extension Message Passing with localStorage, value is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to use Message Passing to pass some data from localStorage to my contentscript. Everything seems right but data is not being passed. I have set up console writes to see if the Message passing is being touched and it is not. This is my first time using JavaScript so the syntax could be wrong.

Here are all the files i'm working with in the extenstion:

[My Code On Gist](https://gist.github.com/1368689)

Comment: Your link title oozes attention to detail. *(I modified it to add clarity.)*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using `sendRequest` as if it is synchronous.

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
  var sText = info.selectionText;
  var daddr = sText.split(' ').join('+');

  chrome.extension.sendRequest(
    {method: "getLocalStorage", key: "saddr"}, 
    function(response) {
      var saddr = response.data;
      var homeTxt = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + 
          "saddr=" + saddr.split(' ').join('+') + "&daddr=";
      var url = homeTxt + daddr;
      chrome.tabs.create({url:url});
      console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
      console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
      console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
    }
 );
}
```

Comment: The way I understood the explanation at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html was that I could send a request to the background.html and have the background.html reply with a response. That is why I am confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: I went ahead and modified my script. you can see the modified version here: https://gist.github.com/1369092 . When running the script nothing is happening within the Message passing. The console is only showing the "Mouse clicked" action. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sterfry1988, What happens if you log before line 3 of background.html?  Do you receive *anything*?

Comment: Your gist doesn't match the code posted above. In particular, you close the anonymous function and sendRequest call after `var saddr = response.data;` on line 13 of `sample.js`.

Comment: I updated the gist to what I have right now, sorry for all the confusion. But as of now. I do not get any errors in the console. But none of my console.logs within the Message passing functions are showing up.

Comment: I was looking in the Developer tool interface and I noticed that when inspecting the background.html element there is no local storage available. But when inspecting the options.html element it shows the values i saved. Does anyone know if this is relevant? if so could the problem be with options.html? The way I understood it was that local storage should be shared between background.html and options.html. Could anyone clarify ?